# Does Windows 2008 Server run acceptably on a Mac Mini with Bootcamp?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, mac-mini

Does anyone have experience installing and running Windows 2008 Server on a Mac Mini (which has either Mac OS X or Mac OS X Server installed), with Bootcamp?

I have an old Dell PC with Windows 2008 server which acts as my domain controller, Exchange server for a small home-office network. It's due for an upgrade as the hardware is so old (and noisy!). I like the idea of having a nice compact, quiet Mac Mini, but want to make sure it can carry out the same duties if I use Win2008 with bootcamp?

Comment: Which Mac Mini do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I bootcamped windows server 2008 R2 on a mac mini that had OSX lion on it and installed the drivers for windows 7 and it works fine. I am now testing to virtualise OSX lion on virtual box in Windows server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for a client, and it worked well.  I also have a similar setup at home using VMWare Fusion, and find it preferable for manageability and flexibility.  (You get to run OSX Server simultaneously, whereas with Boot Camp you're stuck in either OS until a reboot.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing 2008 R2 on a brand new 2012 mac mini. I bought it just for testing (actually, my main interest is KVM, but I'll also be testing VMware ESXi and XenServer.

It is working fine until now (I have already installed Hyper-V role and I am continuing with the tests).

But I couldn't do a "standard" install of bootcamp drivers yet. I have had to install the drivers one-by-one.

Best regards,

Fabio Martins

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be yes, but thats depending on what Mac Mini is being used.

Pretty much you are all set to run on any Intel Mac Mini, hardware wise thanks to the fairly minimal system requirements for Microsoft Windows Server 2008. See the [system requirements for Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/cc196364):

> To use Windows Server 2008 you need*:
>
> [image]